# PhoneGap cell tower information

Tags: networking, cordova, cell

Is there anyway to get celltower information like cellId, cell location, etc using PhoneGap?
I couldn't find any documentations in phoneGap site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to [write a plugin](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.1.0/guide_plugin-development_index.md.html#Plugin%20Development%20Guide) in order to get this information. I know on Android that you can get this information by using the [android.telephony](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/package-summary.html) package.