# How to get cellid through phonegap

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch, cellid, cellinfo

I am creating an app using sencha touch. After that building this with phonegap so that it can be available in multiple platform. Now I need to find out a way to get **user's nearest cell tower location**. So that I can get his location. I don't want to use gps though I know its easy and most accurate.

Is there any way to get that in **phonegap** or **sencha touch**?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12690886/phonegap-cell-tower-information

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this with sencha touch because its a HTML5 framework hence it cannot tap into native functionalities. You should be able to do this with phonegap all you will need to do is create a [plugin](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.1.0/guide_plugin-development_index.md.html#Plugin%20Development%20Guide).

FYI as Ved stated [PhoneGap cell tower information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12690886/phonegap-cell-tower-information)